# Transfer Lightroom watermark and export settings to new computer

Tags: lightroom

I am moving to new computer and I want to transfer Lightroom watermark and export settings to new computer. Any suggestions how I can save the settings and transfer to new computer ?

Comment: Knowing which platform you're on might help. On Mac, settings are in ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Lightroom so you could move them to the same location on the new machine, though it would be far simpler to just migrate your entire user account as part of the initial setup process, then you'd be able to just take up exactly where you left off on the old machine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the Export Setting preset you want to save.
2. Click Export. Save to a directory.

Bring this file to your new machine, and go to the Lightroom export dialog. Make sure to install any export plugins like Mogrify first.

1. Right click in an empty area of the preset listings.
2. Click Import. Navigate to the setting file you brought over.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw an article that lets you copy a folder from your PC - so that you're copying all your watermarks in one go, rather than export/import one at a time. If I find the steps again, I'll add here.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Lightroom Preferences:

- Edit menu > Preferences...
- Click on the "Presets" tab
- In the "Location" panel, click the button "Show Lightroom Presets Folder..."

On PC, File Explorer opens.

- Navigate into the "Lightroom" folder

In here you will see many folders, all relating to presets that you, as an end-user, can customise and configure for Lightroom.

The question here relates to watermarks and export settings. Mine are in the subfolder "Export Presets" and then "User Presets" - but you should either check the folders individually for yourself and choose the ones of interest, or just grab the whole Lightroom folder and copy that (or merge that) into your new Lightroom installation.

This will move all your watermarks in one go. (I have 34 different watermarks I use for different projects, so yeah, the export/import one-by-one wasn't going to be a goer).